# camera.getPicture() returns an unexpected FILE_URI on Android

Tags: cordova, camera, file-uri, cordova-plugin-camera

using the plugin i'm trying to take photo in my app trough the camera.getPicture() method.
Here is the code:

```js
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
});
```

According to the Cordova docs (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html), the success callback should receive something like

**content://media/external/images/media/2** for the file uri, however i only receive this:

**file///data/user/0/com.tld.appname/cache/1642011143203.jpg**.

Trying to use this value as an image src in the WebView does nothing and i'm unable to find the file within the phone filesystem (there is no file///data/user/0/com.tld.appname directory available).
The phone is Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge, Android 7.0.

Other software versions:

- cordova@11.0.0
- cordova-android@10.1.1
- cordova-plugin-camera@6.0.0
- Android SDK Platform 11.0 / API Level 30

What is wrong here?

When i use DATA_URL as destination, it is working fine, however the Cordova docs states this could result in memory problems.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your config so the WebView can load local files from `file://`

```
 <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```